# using virtual function vs dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, function, virtual, dynamic-cast

Instead of using a virtual function, is it fine to use something like:

```
void BaseClass::functionName () {  // BaseClass already has virtual functions
    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...
    if (typeid (*this) == typeid (DerivedClass1))
        // use functions of DerivedClass1 on dynamic_cast<DerivedClass1*>(this)
    else if (typeid (*this) == typeid (DerivedClass2))
        // use functions of DerivedClass2 on dynamic_cast<DerivedClass2*>(this)

    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...
 }
```

It's just that I feel it's not a good idea to use virtual functions for something like the above when it is only a small section that is specialized for the derived classes.  The long code that is used for all the derived classes will then need to be used over and over for all the derived classes (suggesting a helper function(s) just for that).  Of course, I've tested my method and it works (and I suppose with no loss in performance), but I wonder if this is questionable practice.
What if the if-else-if part is used more than once in the function?

And if the common code for all derived classes is relavitively SHORT, then it is better to use virtual functions then, right?

Comment: Tagging with the appropiate language would help your question get discovered by the right users.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "wrong".  The whole point of C++ polymorphism is to avoid code like this.  It's also weird for a base class to have to know about all of its derived classes.  So it sounds like what you're after is the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  If you're not comfortable with putting arbitrary behaviour into the individual classes, you could always apply the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or something similar.

Comment: Also, regarding performance.  If this was in some time-critical inner loop, a bunch of sequential type lookups is going to be *much* slower than a virtual function call.

Comment: virtual functions were invented specifically so you wouldn't need to do things like that.  It was to avoid gigantic if-else/switch statements which were common in the early 70s/80s.  Use RTTI as sparingly as you would use gotos.  It may be used on a small subset now but what about the future?  A maintenance person comes along sees what you are doing and copies the same style but on huge functions.  All of a sudden, this will be used all over the place and we're before you know it, you are back to massive if-elses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
void BaseClass::functionName () {
    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...

    this->some_protected_virtual_member_function();

    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...
 }
```

So the common part is not duplicated and the behavior can still easily have extensions in your children classes without having to add another `if` to your parent class

Comment: Do you mean a `protected` virtual member function?

Comment: Note: said function could be `private` without issues; you are allowed to override `private` `virtual` functions, you just cannot call the implementation of your parent class explicitly.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yet some would argue that the semantic of a private function is not to be known even to your children classes while the protected ones fit exactly this role :)

Comment: @Drax: That is a rather personal interpretation though, isn't it ? I would rather stick to the possibilities opened up by the language, since they are rather explicit: `private` `virtual` functions may be overriden but not called.

Comment: @MatthieuM. And a `protected virtual` function might be both overriden and called, yep i guess your point makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work at all unless the classes have virtual functions. C++ provides only limited reflection: typeid(DerivedClass1)==typeid(DerivedClass2) if there are no virtual functions. The above code also may be slower than simply accessing a virtual function: you'll get a new branch for each type rather than a constant time pointer lookup.

However, the biggest issue with the above code is that it looses polymorphism and encapsulation. The using code must be aware or what DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2 need to do. It needs to be aware of the structures inside DerivedClass1 and DerivedClass2. Also, all the code is piled into one place, making this function possibly hundreds of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the template method pattern here: Just use your existing non-virtual function and have it call a virtual function only for the small section of code that differes between concrete classes. It has the advantage of looking prettier too.

```
void BaseClass::functionName () {
    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...

    functionName_impl();  // Will be virtual (private or protected) and overriden in each child class to do the right work.

    // some LONG code true for all derived classes of BaseClass
    // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a degenerate case of the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
class Base {
public:
    void templated() {
        // do some stuff

        this->hook1();

        // other stuff

        if (/*cond*/) { this->hook2(); }

        size_t acc = 0;
        for (Stuff const& s: /*...*/) { acc += this->hook3(s); }

        // other stuff
    }

private:
    virtual void hook1() {}
    virtual void hook2() {}
    virtual size_t hook3(Stuff const&) { return 0; }
}; // class Base
```

And then a `Derived` class can customize the behavior of the hooks.

A word of warning: this is extremely rigid, by nature, since the `templated` method is not `virtual`; this is a both a virtue and a problem of this pattern, it is good because if you need to change the `templated` method then it is defined in a single place and it is annoying if the hooks provided are not sufficient to customize the behavior.